# Can we create site variance in office 365 site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to create multilingual site in SharePoint online. Can we create multilingual site for public facing website?

I have read that in public site of Office365 we can not create variance.

Can we create variance in internal site collection and make that site collection as public?

Answer (score 2):

The [Variations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/create-a-multi-language-website-HA102886546.aspx) feature is available for SharePoint Online Enterprise (E1), SharePoint Online Enterprise (E3 & E4), SharePoint Online Midsized Business, SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise. If you have another license, e.g. Small Business etc. then you don't have that feature.

To workaround this limit you could try to create sub-folders for every language (EN, FR, etc) and duplicate all pages for every language. See for more details [Office365 public website in different languages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110375/office365-public-website-in-different-languages)