# Office365 public website in different languages

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, multilingual

Looking for a workaround to add to existing public website 2 new languages.

As far as I understand the license of Office 365 Small Business Premium does not include variations. Searching in the internet does not give any results. Are there any other ways (maybe with pure aspx) to implement a multilingual site?

Current site includes a small range of pages with static information such as "about us", "contacts", "our services" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the variations features, you could just manually manage multiple versions of your page content, etc.

For instance, in your Site Pages, create folders: en-US, fr-FR, etc.  In the folders create a version of each site page in the corresponding languages.

Then, as your main page, create some sort of language selector that creates a cookie in JavaScript.  Then, whenever a user hits that page and finds the cookie, redirect them to the main page of the corresponding language.